# React Native - Upgrade 0.56 error [Edited]

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to integrate mobx into my react native application, but having some issues I think is because of the 0.56 react native-update. The error occurs when I use the store-prop or the @observer-decorator (see code below).

The error says: `_$$_REQUIRE(..) is not a function`

I have the latest react native installed (0.56), and have installed Babel Core 7 (Beta 47). 
I also have "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators" (v7, Beta 47). I've also tested with installing: "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime" (v7, Beta 47). First I installed the babel core beta-version 52, but that gave me this error:

`Property right of AssignmentExpression expected node to be of a type ["Expression"] but instead got null`

After some searching it looked like it needed the beta-version 47, so I installed that instead and it looked like it was working until I added the decorator back in to the the code. Then I got the "Require"-error.
I can't find anything about this error on StackOverflow, or anywhere else.

There is no missing peerDependencies.

Here is my package.js:

```
"dependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.11",
    "mobx": "^5.0.3",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.3",
    "plist": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.3.1",
    "xcode": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native-typescript": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "jest": "23.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
```

And .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native-typescript", "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react" ],
  "plugins": [
    [
    "transform-class-properties", { "loose": true },
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
      "helpers": true,
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

And here is the store:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

export class UserStore {
  @observable test = 2;
}
```

And here is the component which uses the store:

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import store from './../mobx/UserStore'

@observer
class NavMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {   
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { userStore } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {userStore.test}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

So the error comes when I use the store-prop or the @observer-decorator. The @observable-decorator works fine in the store.

**Edit:**
It turns out it is not because of the mobx. After I did npm install which updated the react native-version, something is missing/wrong. I actually can't edit any my components. Once I edit them I get a sort of error. The "require"-error is one of them. "_typeof is not a function" is also an error I've been seeing now. Please help, I can't do anything with my app at this time. Is there anything in my packages which is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Update your dependencies with these versions.**

**Set dependancies in package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mobxdemo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "mobx": "^5.0.3",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.3",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-native": "^0.55",
    "react-navigation": "2.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "plugins": [
      "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Set in .babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```